# Octave : fsolve function error

Tags: octave

I have a problem when i use `fsolve`, the programm send me an error, but i don't know why. I should find for `x(2) = 2.96e+13` and `x(1)= 2.72e+22`. 
I tried this for solve my non linear equations : i have 2 equations and 2 unknows:

```
function y = f(x)

global x_rayon_droite
global z1
global r_droite
global x_rayon_gauche
global r_gauche
global y_rayon_droite
global y_rayon_gauche

x_rayon_droite=406
z1=2.72e+22
r_droite = 556.77
x_rayon_gauche=179
r_gauche = 241.42
y_rayon_droite=381
y_rayon_gauche=162


y(1)= x(1).*(x_rayon_droite./z1-x(2)./r_droite.*x_rayon_droite./r_droite)-x(1).*(x_rayon_gauche./z1-x(2)./r_gauche.*x_rayon_gauche./r_gauche)+x_rayon_droite-x_rayon_gauche;
y(2)= x(1).*(y_rayon_droite./z1-x(2)./r_droite.*y_rayon_droite./r_droite)-x(1).*(y_rayon_gauche./z1-x(2)./r_gauche.*y_rayon_gauche./r_gauche)+y_rayon_droite-y_rayon_gauche;

endfunction

[x,info]=fsolve("f",[1e+22;1e13])
```

Error after using fsolve:

[image: Error after using fsolve]

Thx in advance

Comment: Where is the error? I can only see warnings in the image (which is a bad idea, why haven't you added the output as text?)

Comment: The programm doesn t display me a result with values of x1 and x2.
I don't know how to output as text the error.

Comment: First thing to do is to see for what values the function is failing. Use `OutputFcn` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'd do would be to change the call to

```
[x,val,info]=fsolve("f",[1e+22;1e13],options)
```

and experiment with options. In this example, it's easy to find the Jacobian of f analytically, so I'd provide that as the second output of `f`, and put  `options.Jacobian="on"` Another potentially helpful option is AutoScaling = "on", to deal with variables of different scales.

But these don't help much in the specific example, because it's really badly scaled. Here's what the equations actually are:

```
0.0017615*x(1)*x(2) + (8.346e-21)*x(1) = -227
0.0015505*x(1)*x(2) + (8.051e-21)*x(1) = -219
```

This becomes a **linear** system if we introduce a new variable z = x(1)*x(2). But even as a linear system, it's so badly scaled than the solver is likely to give up. Instead, let's introduce `z = (1e+15)*x(1)*x(2)`, which amounts to multiplying the first column by `1e-15`. Then the linear solver returns

```
z = 96810.712  
x(2) = -2.720e+22
```

and so `x(1) = -3.559e-33`

This is kind of insane scale disparity, which makes one wonder if the results are meaningful at all, given that you had 3-5 significant digits in your coefficients.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer !